# How can I retrieve the OwnerId with the describe-instances command?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am trying to display the `OwnerId` of instances in a table format using the [describe-instances](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-instances.html) command, but I can't seem to do that. Is anyone able to help? Here is the command I have currently:

```bash
aws ec2 describe-instances --query 'Reservations[*].Instances[*].{IP:PublicIpAddress,AZ:Placement.AvailabilityZone,STATE:State.Name,KEY:KeyName,VPC:VpcId,ID:InstanceId, INSTANCETYPE:InstanceType}'
```

Thanks,
Bharath

Answer (score 1):

This has two aspects:

#### Output Format

The [AWS Command Line Interface](https://aws.amazon.com/cli/) provides the option to control the output format by means of the `--output` parameter, see [How to Select the Output Format](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/controlling-output.html#d0e1468) for details - currently it supports `json`, `text` and `table`, so `--output table` is what you are after in this regard

#### OwnerId

The `OwnerId` is a property of the parent `Reservations[*]` collection, so you'll need to compose your query differently by starting from there and add the `Instances[0].` path to each other property as follows:

```bash
$ aws ec2 describe-instances --query 'Reservations[*].{OWNERID:OwnerId, IP:Instances[0].PublicIpAddress, AZ:Instances[0].Placement.AvailabilityZone, STATE:Instances[0].State.Name, KEY:Instances[0].KeyName, VPC:Instances[0].VpcId, ID:Instances[0].InstanceId, INSTANCETYPE:Instances[0].InstanceType}' --output table
```

- Please note that `.Instances[*]` is a collection too for a reason, albeit rarely used, which means the facilitated `Reservations[*].Instances[0]` path will only work for the regular case that instances are started one at a time, i.e. **not** something like `aws ec2 run-instances --count 2`, see [run-instances](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/run-instances.html) for details:

> --count (string)
>
> Number of instances to launch. If a single number is provided, it is
>   assumed to be the minimum to launch (defaults to 1). If a range is
>   provided in the form min:max then the first number is interpreted as
>   the minimum number of instances to launch and the second is
>   interpreted as the maximum number of instances to launch.